# Is there any meaningful way in which the tangent function relate to e?

Tags: calculus, analysis, trigonometry

Is there any meaningful value for which $\tan(x)$ relates to $e$? What I mean to say is $\tan(1.21828\ldots)=e$, but is there any significance to this number? i.e. could it be expressed as some rational, algebraic, or notable transcendental number. Or perhaps is there any such number for $x$ in which
$$\tan(\pi x)=e$$
$$\frac{\tan(\pi x)}{x}=e$$
or
$$\frac{\tan(\pi x)}{\pi x}=e$$

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you mean $\tan(x)=\frac{i(e^{-ix}-e^{ix})}{e^{-ix}+e^{ix}}$?  Using this, you should be able to find an explicit form for the $x$ you describe above (but it might not be pretty).  [Clear fractions, multiply through by $e^{ix}$ and substitute $y=e^{ix}$ and solve the quadratic for $y$]

Comment: Is there anything meaningful about the value $\tan^{-1}(e)$? Not really. The [logarithmic form of arctan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Logarithmic_forms) has $\ln$s of $1\pm ix$ instead of just $x$, so evaluating at $x=e$ doesn't yield anything special. But of course trig functions are related to $e$, since they are essentially made out of complex exponentials with that base.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but the $\tan$ function can be expressed in terms of complex exponential functions.

$$\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=-i\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}$$

for $x=i$:

$$\tan(i)=i\frac{e-\frac{1}{e}}{e+\frac{1}{e}}$$